# Is there intermediate computation optimization when using functions.window [Spark]

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `functions.window` to create sliding window computation using Spark and Java. Example code:

```
Column slidingWindow = functions.window(singleIPPerRow.col("timestamp"), "3 hours", "1 seconds");
Dataset<Row> aggregatedResultsForWindow = singleIPPerRow.groupBy(slidingWindow, singleIPPerRow.col("area")).count();
```

The data looks like this:

```
+----------+-------+------+
| timestamp|   area|events|
+----------+-------+------+
|1514452990|domain1|    41|
|1514452991|domain1|    42|
|1514452991|domain1|    50|
|1514452993|domain2|    53|
|1514452994|domain2|    54|
|1514452994|domain3|    54|
|1514452993|domain1|    35|
+----------+-------+------+
```

In real like there are a **lot** of events per timestamp and also note the **large** ratio between the step and the window size.

My question is how many time will the counts be calculated? I mean every timestamp-area count is used by `step/window` different rows in the result. Will Spark save the intermediate results? making every count for a couple be calculated once or will it calculate the result `step/window` for every couple?

Comment: As many times as many steps you generate. There is no optimization here and final aggregation in general happens on different executors.